# How to create dynamic URLs at the base URL of a CMS?

Tags: php, apache, url-routing

I'm displaying user profiles on a PHP website  using usernames as part of the URL that links to the given user profile.

I can achieve this through a controller, the **ProfileController**, but the URL will look like this `thewebsite.com/profile/show_profile/ANYUSERNAMEHERE`

What i want is something similar to Facebook, where the username is appended just after the base URL:

> `https://www.facebook.com/zuck`

I tried passing a variable to the *Index function* (**Index()**) of the *home page controller* (**IndexController**), but the URL becomes `thewebsite.com/index/ANYUSERNAMEHERE` and the base url `thewebsite.com` throws an error:

> Too few arguments to function IndexController::index(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected.

**The home page controller:**

```
<?php
class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // IF LEFT, THE VARIABLE $profile THROWS AN ERROR AT THE BASE URL

    public function index($profile)  
    {
        /** AFTER REMOVING THE $profile VARIABLE ABOVE AND THE 'if'
         *  STATEMENT BELOW, THE ERROR THROWN AT THE BASE URL VANISHES AND                     
         *  THE WEBSITE GOES BACK TO IT'S NORMAL STATE. THIS CODE WAS USED
         *  TRYING TO RENDER THE URL thewebsite.com/ANYUSERNAMEHERE BUT IT  
         *  ONLY WORKS WITH thewebsite.com/index/ANYUSERNAMEHERE
         */  

        if (isset($profile)) {
        $this->View->render('profiles/show_profile', array(
        'profiles' => ProfileModel::getSelectedProfile($profile))
        );

        } else {
        $this->View->render('index/index', array(
        'profiles' => ProfileModel::getAllProfiles()));
    }  

}
```

**The profile controller:**

```
<?php
class ProfileController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        Auth::checkAuthentication();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->View->render('profiles/index', array(
        'profiles' => ProfileModel::getAllProfiles())
        );

    }

    public function show_profile($profile)
    {
        if (isset($profile)) {
        $this->View->render('profiles/show_profile', array(
        'profiles' => ProfileModel::getSelectedProfile($profile))
        );

        } else {

        Redirect::home();

        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting the **base URL** to pass the argument (the username) to the *IndexController's* **Index($profile)** function, but the webpage throws an error and the expected result is being displayed from the wrong URL: `thewebsite.com/index/ANYUSERNAMEHERE`

Comment: just a side note - to clarify, the 'argument' im referring to is the 'username' and is being passed through the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a router based on regular expressions, like [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute), or [Aura.Router](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router).

For example, with FastRoute you'd define and add a route to the  so-called *route collector* (`$r`) like this:

```
$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
    // The /{profile} suffix is optional
    $r->addRoute('GET', '[/{profile}]', 'handler');
});
```

where `handler` is just a generic name for a customizable *route handler* in form of a callable. For example, if you'd additionally use the [PHP-DI/Invoker](https://github.com/PHP-DI/Invoker) library, the route handler (`'handler'`) could look like one of the following callables (at least):

- `[ProfileController::class, 'show_profile']`
- `'ProfileController::show_profile'`

So the complete route definition would be like:

- `$r->addRoute('GET', '[/{profile}]', [ProfileController::class, 'show_profile']);`
- `$r->addRoute('GET', '[/{profile}]', 'ProfileController::show_profile');`

The *placeholder name* (`profile`) corresponds to the name of the parameter of the method `ProfileController::show_profile`:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller {

    public function show_profile($profile) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Even though the URL would look like you want it, e.g. `thewebsite.com/zuck`, I imagine that the placeholder `{profile}` of the above route definition would come in conflict with the fixed pattern parts defined in other route definitions, like `/books` in:

```
$r->addRoute('GET', '[/books/{bookName}]', 'handler');
```

So I suggest to maintain a URL of the form `thewebsite.com/profiles/zuck`, with the route definition:

```
$r->addRoute('GET', '/profiles/{profile}', 'handler');
```

I also suggest to read and apply the [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/) in your code. Especially PSR-1, PSR-4 and PSR-12.